# cocos2d-x 3 fancy effect of removing from stage

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, layer, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have subclasses `Layer` and overrided `onEnter` function like this:

```
void MyLayer::onEnter()
{
    Layer::onEnter();

    Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
    Point visibleOrigin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();
    setPosition(visibleOrigin.x, visibleOrigin.y + visibleSize.height);
    runAction(EaseOut::create(MoveTo::create(1, Vec2(visibleOrigin)), 10));
}
```

This results my layer to enter onto the screen from the top and with ease effect. Now I want to remove the layer from the scent with the same kind of effect. I have tried to use `onExitTransitionDidStart` but it does not help:

```
void MyLayer::onExitTransitionDidStart()
{
    Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
    Point visibleOrigin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();
    runAction(EaseIn::create(MoveTo::create(1, Vec2(visibleOrigin.x, visibleOrigin.y + visibleSize.height)), 10));
}
```

How can I control the way the Layer is being removed from the stage?

Comment: You want on scene replace or just want to remove layer from scene?

Comment: @VikasPatidar I want to run an action on the layer and then remove it from its parent's child list (remove from screen).

Answer (score 0):

You overrode wrong method - you should override `onExit()`. `onExitTransitionDidStart()` is called on layers when their parent scene transition to another scene begins. On the other hand, `onExit()` will be called always, when a layer leaves a scene.

Edit : Your comment is correct.
After giving it a second thought, the easiest way would propably be to write your own 'remove()' method, that would do something like this :

```
void MyLayer::remove() {

    this->runAction(Sequence::create(/*your actions here*/, CallFunc::create(CC_CALLBACK_0(Layer::removeFromParent, this)), NULL);

}
```

This will run an action that removes the node at its end.

Comment: But it is called when layer left the scene already, hence I can not call action on that layer anymore.